# save an image to document properties in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, base64, blob

Currently, I'm umploading a image file from a HTML form, and converting it to base64 with this code:

```
fileImput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (file = this.files[0]) {    
let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = function() {
     var base64String = reader.result;
    }
}
```

I pass base64String to the server and save it in the document's properties.

Till there, it's all perfect. The thing is that I need that image file to include in emails, that use blob format to include images, and in HTML forms, that use base64 format. For more complexity, I get some image files from Drive and get the file's blob with:

```
driveFile.getBlob();
```

I can't find any way to convert, in app script, from **base64** to **blob** and vice versa.

plus, I wish to fully understand blob format. If you can refer to me some good documentation, I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert from the Blob of `driveFile.getBlob()` to the base64 data.
- You want to convert from the base64 data to the Blob of `driveFile.getBlob()`.
- You are using Google Apps Script.

#### 1. Convert from Blob to base64.

```
const blob = DriveApp.getFileById("### fileId ###").getBlob();
const base64 = Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
```

- Base64 data can be converted from the byte array using `Utilities.base64Encode()`.
- In this case, the base64 data has no header. So when you want to use this data as the data URL, please add the header like `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

#### 2. Convert from base64 to Blob.

```
const base64 = "###";
const blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(base64), "### mimeType ###", "### filename ###");
```

- When the base64 data is converted using `Utilities.base64Decode()`, the byte array is returned. In order to convert it to the blob, `Utilities.newBlob()` is used. In this case, mimeType and filename can be included.

#### References:

- [Utilities.base64Encode(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata)
- [Utilities.base64Decode(encoded)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64decodeencoded)
- [Utilities.newBlob(data, contentType, name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata,-contenttype,-name)
- [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: Okay. I'm a fool. I was close, but ... for some stupid reazon, I was using Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe () method and it return something different I guess. I have no words to you than just say thank you, thank you a lot @Tanaike

Comment: @Ppica88 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.